# how to send mail in Laravel admin

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel admin panel.
how to send mail after editing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5MSY.png)

for example:
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Email());

Comment: Can you edit your question and specify if you are using filament or just post the code how you save the updated data ?

Comment: i use this method   https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/model-grid-inline-edit#Select

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few ways you can do this but I recommend the following. First create an event listener for the model you want. So from the photo I am guessing that is the Order model. So create a model observer ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#observers))

```
php artisan make:observer OrderObserver --model=Order
```

After that in your Order model put the followng

```
/**
 * Register any events for your application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    User::observe(OrderObserver::class);
}
```

Then create an new notification by following the [guide in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#mail-notifications). And finally in the updated method in your observer put the following

```
Mail::to(auth()->user()->email)->send(new YourNotification());
```

Comment: in the observer, you can find out that only the status has been updated? i need to send email only after status update

Comment: Yes John, you have an explicit updated method in your observer!